# How to reduce the size of my dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

working on NLP problem

I ended up with a big features dataset

```
dfMethod
Out[2]: 
      c0000167  c0000294  c0000545  ...  c4721555  c4759703  c4759772
0            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
2            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
4            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
3995         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3996         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3997         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3998         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3999         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0

[4000 rows x 14317 columns]
```

I want to remove columns with the smallest repetition (i.e. the columns with the smallest sum of of all records)

so if my columns sum would look like this

```
Sum of c0000167 = 7523
Sum of c0000294 = 8330
Sum of c0000545 = 502
Sum of c4721555 = 51
Sum of c4759703 = 9628
```

in the end, I want to only keep the top 5000 columns based on the sum of each column?

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a big dataframe `big_df` you can get the top columns with the following:

```
N = 5000
big_df[big_df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index[:N]]
```

Breaking this down:

```
big_df.sum()  # Gives the sums you mentioned
.sort_values(ascending=False)  # Sort the sums in descending order
.index  # because .sum() defaults to axis=0, the index is your columns
[:N]  # grab first N items
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited after author comment.
Let's consider df a pandas DataFrame. Preparing the filter, select top 5000 sum columns:

```
df_sum = df.sum() # avoid repeating df.sum() next line
co = sorted([(c, v) for (c, v) in list(zip(df_sum.keys(), df_sum.values))], key = lambda row: row[1], reverse = True)[0:5000]
# fixed trouble of sum value greater than 5000, but the top 5000.
co = [row[0] for row in co]
# convert to a list of column names of interest
```

After filter columns in co:

```
df = df.filter(items = co)
df
```

Comment: Couple things here: (1) you call `df.sum` twice and this dataframe is pretty big, (2) the question asks for the top 5000 columns, not columns with a sum greater than 5000.